# how long will Google continue updating the angular1.x?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here comes a problem to our project.We would use angular 1.x in our project,which we prepared to maintain for 3 years or more. But can angular1.x stand on 3 years later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should ask that to google not stackoverflow.

Anyways as far as I know AngularJs is open source, and made by various people not just people who work at google. You can help to fix bux and stabilize the framework in the future. And I will assume others will also for legacy apps at that point.

That being said, 3 years should not be a problem I don't expect angular2 to have a 1.0 at the end of this year, though Beta is already pretty stable.

Comment: Will Google just leave the angular1.x to the community?

Comment: I don't know I'm not google. But since you just can go fork the repo, the community can take over even if google leaves it to rot. So in theory yes.

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 progress here: https://github.com/angular/angular/milestones

As you can see from the current progress, there's still quite some time left before Angular2 can be considered a "robust" framework. 
You can rest assured that Angular1 will be around for quite some time, because its open-source and it will probably continue to get sub-releases for several years to come.

I would also imagine that further down the line it will be much easier to migrate from Angular version `1.x` to `2.x`.